# JMeter configuration: Performance testing after Login

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to test the performance of a specific operation in my webapp. In order to do that, I have to first login. Basically I have two HTTP-Request, one for logging in and another one I want to test with multiple simultaneous Threads (=users).

In order to get comparable results on the second request, I need the first request to be finished by all Threads, so that the first request doesn'T interfere with the performance of the second request.

I tried splitting up the process into multiple ThreadGroups or in a setUp-ThreadGroup and a ThreadGroup, the problem is, that the login request stores the login information into the HTTPSession and I would need to "share" the session accross those ThreadGroups.

I did some research but I can't find a lot i can make sense of. Is there an easy way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in single Thread Group using [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) added to the 2nd request sampler as child, with value of `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` = total number of threads.

This will pause execution of 2nd request until 1st one will be completed with all the threads.

```
Thread Group
Number of Threads = N
+- Login Request
+- 1st Request
   +- Synchronizing Timer
      Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by = N
+- 2nd Request
   +- Synchronizing Timer
      Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by = N
```