# Simultaneous users for web load tests in JMeter?

Tags: performance, load, webserver, jmeter

I have made some PHP scripts and I want to test the response time for **simultaneous users** in [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/). This scripts are run in a very short time (50 miliseconds).

What I would like to do is to simulate a load test from 1 to 50 of users where each user (thread) repeats the request for an unlimited period. So first we will have 1 user, after 2 **simultaneous users**, after 3 ... and so on.

I am trying to do it but with I have is response times where it is evident that there is no simultaneous request.

With HP loaddrunner we can define **number of iterations for each thread**, is this possible in JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly use these 2 thread group implementations

- [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup)
- [Ultimate Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup)

from [Jmeter Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/) package, that let you set load-increase for you scenario as you want.

As well you can also look onto [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) if you want ["better" concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482982/jmeter-configuration-performance-testing-after-login/10484153#10484153) - but this is rather stress-testcase than load one.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I am using the [Stepping Thread Group](http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup) and it does exactly what I want :-)